# How to store a json array with .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, json

I Have a json array like

```
[{"name":"A","value":"A"},{"name":"B","value":"B"},{"name":"C","value":"C"}]
```

How can i pass(to the backend) and store(in db) that javascript object with asp.net??

**EDIT:**

OK to make it clearer, in some page, i got a javascript object

```
var array = [{"name":"A","value":"A"},{"name":"B","value":"B"},{"name":"C","value":"C"}];
```

, how can i pass it to some handler (like using

```
`$.post({url:"handler.ashx", data:array})
```

??), then in backend how can i save it into database or load this array later??

**OR**:

I'll appreciate it if u teach me how to convert

```
var array = [{"name":"A","value":"A"},{"name":"B","value":"B"},{"name":"C","value":"C"}];
```

into:

```
var arraystring = '[{"name":"A","value":"A"},{"name":"B","value":"B"},{"name":"C","value":"C"}]';
```

**EDIT2**:

Now i use the string-solution (traversal the array and add some '"' ':' ',' '{}' manually) as i mentioned just above, is there any potential problems??

Comment: how do you want to store it? As a JSON string, as separate records? If you could also show the relevant target db schema that would help

Comment: You are asking a very broad, abstract question. 1) How to do ajax, 2) how to convert JSON to .net classes/objects; 3) how to store objects in a database. You might as well be asking "how do I create a web application." Try being a little more specific. What have you done so far? What technologies are you using - database, jQuery, etc.

Comment: ASP.NET Webforms or MVC?

Comment: @balexandre - I assume Web Forms since he mentioned the use of a Handler.

Comment: @balexandre Does Webforms or MVC really matter??

Comment: Yes as in MVC3 you have `FormCollection` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx that you could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options when dealing with JSON on .NET

- You can simply keep the array as is in the DB and retrieve it as is and use it
- You can parse it into an Object using [JSON.NET Library](http://json.codeplex.com/)

for example on the 2nd case you simple use the JSON.NET method:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.KeyValuePairConverter
```

Or be fancy and use a [Custom Deserialize](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) as it's really easy to pass to and from JSON.

---

Let's imagine that you are posting something like this:

```
$.post("myForm.aspx",
       [{"name":"A","value":"A"},{"name":"B","value":"B"},{"name":"C","value":"C"}],
       function() {
          // all done.
       });
```

This will be converted to `A,B,C` when requesting the data using `Request.Form["name"]` or simply `Request["name"]` so you should change all the naming convention first and then you can simple use `Request["nameA"]`, `Request["nameB"]`, etc...

Comment: There's also at least two framework JSON serializers that work just fine for most purposes, `JavascriptSerializer` and `DataContractJSONSerializer`. Nothing against the Newtonsoft one, I've used it and its great, but its also an unneeded dependency for many purposes.

Comment: I used Newtonsoft since the beginning when nothing more was that good, that's why I'm to dependent on it :)

Answer (score 0):

You would store it just like any other string you wanted to store in the database. If you want to re-instantiate it later in JavaScript you use the eval() function on the string to convert it back into an object.

Comment: But now, it's not a string, isn't it? And how can i pass it to the backend? When i use $.post, it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to de-serialize the json into object and save it to db as records.

Check JSON.NET library http://json.codeplex.com/

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string value{get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    string json ="[{\"name\":\"A\",\"value\":\"A\"},{\"name\":\"B\",\"value\":\"B\"},{\"name\":\"C\",\"value\":\"C\"}]";
    IList<MyObj> arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyObj>>(json);

    foreach(MyObj o in arr)
    {
        //add each object to db...
        Console.WriteLine(o.name+":"+o.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out that using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify is a not-bad solution.